# Javascript/AJAX JSON encode of array - How to use the data when recived?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I want to get all the images from a folder on the server, i do this with a ajax call

```
files = glob('assets/img/daily/*'); // get all file names
$imageArr;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $imageArr[] = $file;
}
//$imageJSON = ['img01' => $imgArr[0], 'img02' => $imgArr[1], 'img02' => $imgArr[2]];
//$jsonObj = json_encode($imageArr);
$jsonObj = json_encode($imageArr);

echo $jsonObj;
```

I can echo the json encode which looks like this

```
["assets\/img\/daily\/163.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/168.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/197.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/223.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/232.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/260.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/297.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/30.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/310.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/333.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/339.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/411.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/421.jpeg","assets\/img\/daily\/427.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/46.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/52.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/86.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/background.jpg","assets\/img\/daily\/booby.png","assets\/img\/daily\/booty.png"]
```

UPDATE

Here are my Javascript/AJAX/HTML

```
<p id="raw"></p>
<br><br>
<p id="json"></p>
<script>
    var raw, json;
    raw = document.getElementById("raw");
    json = document.getElementById("json");
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "ajax.php";
            http.open("POST", url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
//                    alert(this.responseText);
                    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    raw.textContent = this.responseText;
                    json.textContent = jsonObj;
                }
            };
            http.send();
</script>
```

How do i access the data? i cant do `jsonObj.name` since none of the outputs is named? the `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText)` i recieve looks like this

```
assets/img/daily/30.jpg,assets/img/daily/46.jpg,assets/img/daily/background.jpg,assets/img/daily/booby.png,assets/img/daily/booty.png,assets/img/daily/chrome.png,assets/img/daily/default.png,assets/img/daily/defaults.png
```

Comment: try var_dump($jsonObj)

Comment: `$jsonObj` is a string right? so `$jsonObj[0]` is the first character of that string, which is `"["`

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Where does the JavaScript fit in all of this?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 4):

> But my problem is if i try to get data from this JSON obj like echo $jsonObj[0] i will recieve this as output "["

JSON is a string. It is designed to be transmitted over HTTP, stored in files, etc. It isn't designed to be processed without being parsed first. You need to convert it to an array to be able to usefully use it.

… except you don't because the data is **already** available an array; you used it as input to `json_encode`.

Just use the `$imageArr` variable instead of `$jsonObj`

Comment: i will actually echo the json string for an ajax call

Comment: @Javaish — Then echo the string instead of trying to loop over it.

Comment: @Javaish — You've changed it into a completely different question. Now it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript